# Открыть из консоли вкладку с терминалом и вкладку с файлом в Vim 8

Tags: консоль, vim

В *Vim 8* добавили терминал, который вызывается командой `:terminal`. Вопрос: как из командной строки вызвать *vim,* чтобы в первой вкладке сразу открылся терминал, а во второй — файл? Что-то типа такого (не работает):

```sh
$ vim -p :terminal readme.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vim -c ':tab terminal' -c 'tabm 0' -p readme.txt
```

После загрузки буфера, выполняется открытие новой вкладки с терминалом, перемещение текущей вкладки в начало.

```
vim -c ':tab terminal' -c 'tabm 0' -c ':tabn' -p readme.txt
```

Покажет содержимое файла, после загрузки.